# Using HTML5 tooltip gets page ruined on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So I wrote [this page](https://budker.uni-mainz.de/gnome/) from scratch, using php, python and bash. The page collects data from the server, and displays it.

I would like to add tooltips on the world map, such that the user could see the station name on click/mouseover. I followed [this tutorial](http://red-team-design.com/image-map-with-css3-jquery-tooltips/).

1- I wrapped my world image with #wrapper

2- I added the CSS code

3- I added the Javascript code.

This appeared to look fine in the beginning and the tooltip is working, but on Google Chrome, like 90% of the time (I'm on Windows 10 viewing this) I suddenly see that the world map gets messed up, as follows, getting over the data plots:

[image]

While it should look like this:

[image]

I noticed that this problem happens in Google Chrome, and not on Mozilla Firefox or Microsoft Edge... Why is this happening? I have the feeling that a simple float command could fix it. Could you please help me with this? Why is this happening?

If you require any additional information please ask.

**UPDATE:**

I noticed removing this part of the script solves the problem:

```
    $('#wrapper').css({'width':$('#wrapper img').width(),
                  'height':$('#wrapper img').height()
})
```

But then the tooltip doesn't work.

Comment: What version of chrome? Seems to be working for me, scratch that. worked first load then failed after that

Comment: Cant reproduce in chrome here - Only thing here is that the tooltips seems misplaced, if its suppose to show when hoovering the points.

http://i61.tinypic.com/6i9w8x.png

Comment: @Christer The misplacement is fine I haven't set the coordinates properly yet. But see DGS's comment. It worked in the beginning then it got messed. This is exactly what happened with me!

Comment: @DGS My chrome version is: 44.0.2403.130 m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `rome.js` included in `head` section. If it will be loaded earlier then html body, it will be executed earlier then dom content loaded.
So the first time evertything works, because `js` is loading with dom content. After first refresh `js` will be taken from cache and executed too early.

So you should prevent that using jquery [`$(document).ready()` method](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) or [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

Or you could simply include your `rome.js` in the end of the `body` section.

Comment: Also, try to move your wrapper properties setup after `#wrapper img` loaded. Like     `$('#wrapper img').on('load', function () {
        $('#wrapper').css({'width':$('#wrapper img').width(),
                     'height':$('#wrapper img').height()
        })
    });`

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: I meant you should listen load event on your image, not move to the end of file, check the code above, try to use it

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems to have solved the problem. Apparently the problem was that the image size was being loaded before the image is being available, causing the image size to appear wrong and gets itself positioned wrongly. I'm grateful :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are two things not working out here:

1. You don't have a [doctype](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype).
2. You have some `<style>` and `<script>` tags before your `<html>`. They should be inside your `<head>` or `<body>`

Comment: So you have something like: `<!doctype html><html><head> [your <style>s and <script>s] </head> <body> [ the page ] </body></html>` ? It works for me locally with the changes.

Comment: Yes. Please check the source.

Comment: It actually works for me now in chrome (refresh cache if needed).